# Android what happens when recent button is clicked, not home button or back button

Tags: android

I searched on stackoverflow, people have different opinions, so I hope your answer can refer me to some source that I can believe.

What activity lifecycle methods will be called when you click on recent button when the app is in resumed state (running in foreground and interacting with user) ?

Comment: That is likely to vary by OS version and manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

*When you click on recent button  onPause() will be called for current app.if you open different app from recent screen ,onRestart()-->onStart()-->onResume() will be called first then if the recently selected app  covers entire screen, onStop() called for previous app.*

*When you click on recent button  onPause() will be called for current app,if you select same app after click on recent button, onResume() called again for same app.*

[look at here to know more about lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)